# how keep data between activities?

Tags: android

I have 2 activities A and B.

On Activity A there is a list and a button who goes on B.
On Activity B there is a button who goes on A.

What i am doing.

- Go to A
- list is filled
- click on the button
- go to B
- click on the button
- go back to A

After the list is empty. I have to refill it. Why. My code doesn't use finish()

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(_context, classToGo);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Is activity A your first activity when you launch the app? Or you come to activity A from some other activity and then from A you go to B?

Comment: Yes,it is the first Activity.

Comment: Basically when you do a startActivity(intent), it starts a new activity, unless you set some flags on the intent. So what you see is a new activity. You can see this when you use back button to go backwards. And for list to be empty we need to see some part of code as to why it is not populated in new activity.

Comment: so each time i go back to A. onCreate it called ?

Comment: Yes. If you use startActivity(intent) you go to "new" A and onCreate onStart onResume all are called. and when using device back button you go to old A and onResume is called, if that was not destroyed or stopped yet

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from a to b:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
intent.putExtra("data", "string data");
startActivity(intent);
```

To receive data at class B from A:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
String value = extras.getString("data");
}
```

Note that you can pass only integer,double,float,boolean and string types

Comment: I don't want pass data between A and B. I just want when go back to A, my data doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using intent to go back on activity A, it will create a new Activity, if you want go back from B to A on button click. Then on Button click call the method.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    Activity_B_context.this.finish();
    }
```

And if you Want data to save on Activity A then use SharedPreferences like

[SharedPreferences example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)